# Cannot edit the Rich Text Formatting options after upgrade from 5.1

Tags: 2011, xslt

After a migration from Tridion 5.1 to SDL Tridion 2011 I am having a problem when I try to edit the features in Rich Text Formatting fields in some schemas. In the schemas with the issue I cannot edit the fields because the window is opening empty with only the confirmation button.

In the other schemas with Rich Text Formatting fields I have no problems editing the Xslt filtering option.

I have also tried refreshing the window by pressing F5 not just once but many times and the result was almost the same as it opens the window but the window is still empty. If I edit something in there it's not possible to save the changes but as I said, it happens only in some schemas, not in all.

Could anybody help me? It's SDL Tridion 2011 SP1-HR1.

Comment: have you tried pressing F5 on the empty window? (when the browser asks if you are sure you want to leave the page, choose yes and continue)

Comment: @Lorenzo If you re-post the answer as yourself I can delete user623's answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

We had similar issues after migration, if you are using any custom XSLT for that particular RTF fields. You have to either replace with new XSLT of 2011 or Merge old and new XSLT.

also check this [StackExchange link](http://goo.gl/iyXRSG) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Finally I solved the problem pasting from a new schema in SDL Tridion 2011 the "tcm:FilterXSLT..." node in the old schema's source (because it was the only part of the schema where I could edit the xsl). After that, when I pressed the Rich Text Formatting Features, the pop up window opened with no problems and I could finally edit the Xslt filter, and the allowed styles in there. I added the old xsl after the last "template" node in the source as well. And it was done.

Still I don't know why it happened after the migration, at least, by now it's working. Thank you very much.